# inner_join on dataset with different number of keys

Tags: r, inner-join

I have two dataset:
df1: has two column (v1 and v2)
df2: has 3 column (v3, v4 and v5)

i want to do inner_join searching for value of df1/column2 present in df2 in column 1 or 2 or 3 alternatively. I tryed something like:

```
df1%>%
  inner_join(., df2,
             by=c("v2"="v3","v2"="v4","v2"="v5")=->test
```

but is not working , i can't found any tips in internet
Thank you in advace!

Comment: Without seeing what df1 and df2 are, it is really quite impossible to tell you why things are not working the way you expect. Please [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for how to ask a good question on SO.

Comment: You can try a nested `inner_join()`.